# Как передать список id пользователей в user_ids?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

Пишу бота для вк и чтобы отправить сразу нескольким пользователям одно и то же сообщение в библиотеке vk_api, есть

```
vk_session.method('messages.send', {передаём параметры в том числе и user_ids})
```

В документации написано, что нужно передавать список id разделённых запятой, я пробовал передать в параметр user_ids и питоновский список, и кортеж, и множество, но оно никак не работает, подскажите как и что правильно передавать в этот параметр, чтобы он работал

Comment: Можно ссылку на документацию, где сказано, что надо так передавать?

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/messages.send

Comment: `values={'user_ids':[1,2,3]}` так пробовали?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/lQOBD7r

Comment: @dIm0n как видно на скрине, в функцию приходит список, но по итогу сообщение приходит только одному пользователю

Comment: @dIm0n заметил закономерность, что сообщение отправляется только последнему пользователю в списке

Comment: @dIm0n Если я передаю id пользователей в виде кортежа или списка, то берётся последний id, а если множество, то первый